# Result code code is -1 and returned intent is null in onActivityResult()

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to initialize image picker dialog by this code:
Intent chooserIntent = null;

```
    List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();

    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(context)));
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, pickIntent);
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, takePhotoIntent);

    if (intentList.size() > 0) {
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1), "");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[intentList.size()]));
    }
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE_ID);
```

But there

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case PICK_IMAGE_ID:
                Bitmap bitmap = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this, resultCode, data);
                currentImageButton.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Im getting null intent and -1 resultCode

I've added there permissions to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Code works fine on most devices but fails on samsung duos. Where I wrong?

**UPD**

[activity](https://github.com/zuberok/factory/blob/master/app/src/main/java/kg/zuber/factory/activities/SubchapterEditActivity.java)

[image picker class](https://github.com/zuberok/factory/blob/master/app/src/main/java/kg/zuber/factory/utils/ImagePicker.java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's OK, that you're getting `-1` - it means `public static final int RESULT_OK` (see `Activity` class).

**`Null` as an intent means, that you already defined your output uri here:**

`i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(context)));`

(I.e. you can just use the `Uri`, once you got confirmation, that capturing is done)

Regarding image picking, I do it this way (it's pretty much the same, as Google suggests in the [Taking Photos Simply](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) article):

```
.....
private Uri capturedImageURI;
.....

    capturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(createImageFile());
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageURI);
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK).setType("image/*"), "Select Picture");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 42);

.....

public File createImageFile() {
    File imageStorageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            , "MyAppPictures");

    if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
        imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
    }

    return new File(
            imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                    + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    + ".jpg");
}    

.....

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
             capturedImageURI = data.getData();  
        }
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.capturedImageView)).setImageURI(capturedImageURI);
    }
}
```

**NB!** You'll need these permissions to make it work:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And in *Android 6.0* you'll have to check permissions, before getting data from external storage.

Comment: Thank you. Problem was with permissions. Problem was hard to resolve becauser some devices did not care about perms.